# How to reconfigure NTFS for macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: macos

I have installed Mounty for NTFS and some similar apps and was not satisfied with any so removed all of them. Now I am unable to access any external hard disk; it is not getting mounted. How can I reconfigure it? I am using macOS Ventura 13.3.1.

How can I reconfigure NTFS read-only mode?

Comment: I'm still on 11.7 so can't test your OS, but I've always had success with this script: https://sourceforge.net/projects/native-ntfs-osx/

Comment: Did you remove them by just deleting the files, or did you follow the uninstall instructions the vendor provided?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install it again and mount it as read only. Once you have it mounted as read only, then you can uninstall it again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Specifically, what does “reinstall it” refer to?  macOS?  NTFS support? The Windows server?  It’s helpful to clearly articulate your answer so it can stand on its own.